# What is the degree of $A(\theta)=\theta+\pi$?

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

What is the degree of the circle function $A: S^1 \rightarrow S^1$, $A(\theta)=\theta+\pi$?

Considering coefficient of $\theta$ to be $1$ and ignoring translation $\pi$ so $deg (A)=1$. On the other hand, $A$ is the antipodal map that maps each point 
on the circle to the point opposite it through the center so is like $f(\theta)=-\theta$ so should be $deg(A)=-1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The degree of a map is a homotopy invariant, and since your map $A$ is homotopic to the identity (can you see why?) the degree should be $1$.

The degree of the antipodal map is not always $-1$. It depends on the dimension of the sphere on which it is defined. On the $1$-sphere, the circle, it has degree $1$. Can you find a formula for the degree of the antipodal map on the $n$-sphere $S^n$?

Comment: I can see why A is homotopic to the identity. But why on the 1-sphere the antipodal map has degree 1? And, Would you please guide me how can I find a formula for the degree of the antipodal map on the n-sphere? I have no idea! Thank you.

Comment: Why shouldn't it have degree $1$? As for the general formula, try to write the antipodal map on the $n$-sphere as the composition of some number of reflections.

Comment: And about $deg(A)$, can we say is $A$ homotopic to identity becasue by a homotopy $F(\theta, t)=\theta+(t-1)\pi$? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct homotopy.